# How to set schema for janusgraph for batch-loading using python

Tags: python, gremlin, bulk-load, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am trying to bulk-load data into a janusgraph 0.2 over HBase. I am using gremlinpython library of python. For bulk-loading, I set `storage.batch-loading` to `true`, and now have to define the schema for the graph.

I found documentation to set schema for the graph (https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/schema.html & https://docs.janusgraph.org/0.2.0/advanced-schema.html).

It suggests some basic code for schema :

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
follow = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel('follow').multiplicity(MULTI).make()
mother = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel('mother').multiplicity(MANY2ONE).make()
mgmt.commit()
```

I connected to the graph using gremlinpython library of python. This is what I'm doing :

```
from    gremlin_python                                  import  statics
from    gremlin_python.structure.graph                  import  Graph
from    gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal          import  __
from    gremlin_python.process.strategies               import  *
from    gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection  import      DriverRemoteConnection
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  T
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  Order
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  Cardinality
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  Column
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  Direction
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  Operator
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  P
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  Pop
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  Scope
from    gremlin_python.process.traversal                import  Barrier

from    config                                          import  graph_url, graph_name

graph = Graph()
drc = DriverRemoteConnection(graph_url, graph_name)

g = graph.traversal().withRemote(drc)

# I successfully get g here, I check it by :
# g.V().count().next()
```

Now my question is, where should I set the schema. I tried to do `mgmt = graph.openManagement()` after the commented out lines, but it doesn't work.

---

#### Update

It works on the gremlin console as :

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> 
gremlin> :> mgmt = graph.openManagement()
==>org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@625dfab4
```

But any furthur commands don't work here :

```
:> follow = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel('follow').multiplicity(MULTI).make()
No such property: mgmt for class: Script10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [gremlinpython](https://pypi.org/project/gremlinpython/#description) driver is a [Gremlin Language Variant](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/gremlin-language-variants/) (GLV), which allows you to use Gremlin natively in a programming language, Python. The JanusGraph schema definitions are specific to the JanusGraph db, however the gremlinpython GLV is a generic TinkerPop driver, so it doesn't have the constructs to call db-specific APIs.

As you've noted, you could declare your schema through the Gremlin Console. Another alternative is to use a string-based Gremlin driver, like [gremlinclient](https://gremlinclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [gremlinpy](https://github.com/emehrkay/gremlinpy), and send your schema as a string query to the server.

Comment: When on the gremlin console, after defining `mgmt`, I am unable to use it again, as I have mentioned in the very end. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Because you created the remote connection as sessionless. Check out the TinkerPop docs on how to use [sessions](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#console-sessions). `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session`